# How to move to specific line in a file on matching the string C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, windows-forms-designer

Say i have a file *contacts.txt* with the content:

```
adam
adam@gmail.com
kris
kris@gmail.com
james
james@gmail.com
```

Also I've stored the contents of the file in the ListView (ListView1) like:

```
adam    adam@gmail.com
kris    kris@gmail.com
james   james@gmail.com
```

And I have used the contextmenustrip with item Update.

Say on the ListView I right click on the james line and select update then a new form will be loaded asking name and email to update.

On entering the name & email into the textboxes and after update button click corresponding persons name and email must be updated in the contacts.txt file and that form will be closed and returns to previous form.

Say I change the name of the james to bond & email to bond@gmail.com.

Now the content should be:

```
adam
adam@gmail.com
kris
kris@gmail.com
bond 
bond@gmail.com
```

Also on the right click of the update as the new form will be loaded prompting to enter name and email for this instance. Say I click on the james line in the ListView I want the james to be placed on the name and james@gmail.com to be placed on the email on the textboxes of the new form click of the updatemenustrip.

Comment: Can there be a duplicate in names? Like have two entries of "bond" but have two different mails for them?

Comment: is the file too long that you can't read it completely and then write it back again?

Comment: No there cant be duplicate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it. Here are a few ones. I'll use your example...

1. Read all the lines of the file in memory (eg. `string[]`). For every line in the array, if you find `james`, replace it with `bond`, and in the next position write `bond@gmail.com`. Then write back all the lines to the same file

   ```
   var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt");

   for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
       var line = lines[i];
       if (line == "james") {
           lines[i] = "bond";
           lines[i + 1] = "bond@gmail.com";
       }
   }

   File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test2.txt", lines);
   ```
2. Read the entire text, and replace those specific values using regular expression:

   ```
   var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

   string oldName = "james";
   string newName = "bond";
   string oldEmail = "james@gmail.com";
   string newEmail = "bond@gmail.com";

   var newText = Regex.Replace(
       text,
       string.Format(@"{0}([\n\r]+){1}", Regex.Escape(oldName), Regex.Escape(oldEmail)),
       string.Format(@"{0}$1{1}", newName, newEmail));

   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", newText);
   ```

Comment: also on the right click of the update as the new form will be loaded prompting to enter name and email for this instance say i click on the james line in the listview i want the james to be placed on the name and james@gmail.com to be placed on the email on the textboxes of the new form click of the updatemenustrip.

Comment: Just put that code in a function that receives 4 parameters: `oldName`, which you already know. `newName`, the one entered in the textbox, `oldEmail`, which you already know, and `newEmail`, also entered in the textbox.

Comment: Say for the same if we want to delete a line from a file C# that matches the string what to do

Comment: If you want, we can move this conversation to a chat, because you're asking for something different now. You can do: `Regex.Replace(text, string.Format("{0}[\r\n]", Regex.Escape(line)), "");` where `line` is the line content you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

After update, `ListView.items` is up to date. Iterate `ListView.items` and write each item back to the file.

Comment: also on the right click of the update as the new form will be loaded prompting to enter name and email for this instance say i click on the james line in the listview i want the james to be placed on the name and james@gmail.com to be placed on the email on the textboxes of the new form click of the updatemenustrip